# Обработчик нажатий на клавишу

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Мне нужно сделать небольшую программу, которая должна после 8 введёных символов нажимать на клавишу F1(это я уже сделал)`if ( == 8) {keybd_event('F1', 0, 0, 0);keybd_event('F1', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);numb = 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Введённых **КУДА**?
Для консоли можно так:

```
#include <conio.h>
int c = 0;
char ch;
while (c < 8){
    ch = _getch();
    cout << ch;
    c++;
}
```

Comment: Если вы хотите уточнить у автора что-то по вопросу -- лучше сначала дожидаться ответа, чтобы не пришлось удалять/переписывать ответ.

Comment: Введённых просто на клавиатуре(asynckeystatr)

Comment: @Павел-Вороник Здесь смотрели https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/keyboard-input что вам подходит?

Comment: Мне подходит GetAsyncKeyState, мне нужно, чтобы после 8 введенных символов в поисковой строке в браузере, нажималось F1. При помощи JS  так сделать нельзя,  а отследить кол-во нажатых клавиш можно.
Я пытался сделать так: if (GetAsyncKeyState(!(VK_F3)) { i++, но это не работает

Comment: @ПавелВороник Из какого процесса нужно следить за браузером? Из самого браузера или из внешней программы?

Comment: из внешней программы.